# Enabling Authorize button for auth in swagger API using springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger-ui, openapi, springdoc-openapi-ui

[image]

How to enable authorize button on the top right for OAuth 2.0

I added `springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui` for spring boot version 3.0.2. Can someone help me enable authorize button

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem to add authorize button for Bearer autorisation. The solution I find is configure SpringSecurityConfig:

```java
@Configuration
@SecurityScheme(type = SecuritySchemeType.HTTP, name = "bearerAuth", scheme = "bearer")
public class SpringSecurityConfig {}
```

In your specific case, I think, you can configure with `type = SecuritySchemeType.OAUTH2`

And the usage via `@SecurityRequirement` is somethink like this:

```java
@RestController
@SecurityRequirement(name = "bearerAuth") // on full class
public class PingController {
    @SecurityRequirement(name = "bearerAuth") // or only on specific method
    @GetMapping("/ping")
    public String ping() {
        return "pong";
    }
}
```

The result to authorize:
[auth button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jts2q.png);
[auth flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmAxI.png)

And the method marked in this way:
[api marked with lock icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zZfD.png)
It will automaticly add `Authorization: Bearer <value you enter>` header to this request